# How to get the parameter value in object with variable ?<Typescript>

Tags: typescript

```
var data = {
   '001': {
      'user': 'bob',
      'age': 12
   },
   '002': {
      'user': 'john',
      'age': 5
   }
}

var targetKey = '001';
var result = data[targetKey];
console.log(result);
```

I have an object, and I would like to get the value by a key variable. However, an error occur:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type
```

What changes I need to make to get the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set index signature for `data`.

```
var data: { [index: string] : object } = {
   '001': {
      'user': 'bob',
      'age': 12
   },
   '002': {
      'user': 'john',
      'age': 5
   }
};

var targetKey = '001';
var result = data[targetKey];
console.log(result);
```